# in Ruby, how do I push elements to the end of a range?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to push elements onto the end of a range without converting it into an array then back to a range?

```
r = 1..10
=> 1..10

r << 11
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for 1..10:Range

r.push 11
NoMethodError: undefined method `push' for 1..10:Range
```

Comment: A range is simply an interval. A start and an end. You don't just push values on the end of a Range. You either convert the Range to an array (items = range.to_a; items << 11). Or you create a new range.. `Range.new(range.begin, 11)`

Comment: @injekt You should add it as an answer.

Comment: oh, great, `Range.new` does the trick, thank you. would you post an answer for me to accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A range is simply an interval. A start and an end. You don't just push values on the end of a Range. You either convert the Range to an array

```
items = range.to_a
items << 11
```

Or you create a new range..

```
Range.new(range.begin, 11)
```

EDIT: The reason we use #begin on the range and not #first is because `first` and `last` build a new array from the Range, we don't want that.. we just want the `begin` or `end` values instead.

Comment: doh, "You can accept an answer in 2 minutes", why this annoying limitations?

Comment: @BillParker Hang around SO for a while longer, you'll pass the point threshold in no time :-)

Comment: You want to be careful converting a range to an array. For small ranges it's relatively safe, but large ranges can consume memory and CPU time as the intermediate values are generated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. A Range is not an Array, or a Set, or a collection at all really. It's just a representation of an upper and lower bound. You can iterate one because it's possible to step between the upper and lower bounds. You can also turn one into an Array (using `Range#to_a`), which just iterates and collects the values into an Array.

If you want to expand or shrink the Range, create a new Range based on its `#begin` and `#end`.

```
new_range = Range(old_range.begin, old_range.end + 1)
```

Comment: Using `first` and `last` converts the Range to an Array first. You want `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Right you are. Fixed, thanks ;) (They may be optimized, but they were the wrong methods indeed)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend a range by pushing the next elements to it. You can however extend the Range class to support for modifying ranges in any way you need.

```
class Range
  def end_at(x)
    Range.new(self.begin, x)
  end

  def start_at(x)
    Range.new(x, self.end)
  end
end

# Initial Range
range = 1..10

# New end
p range.end_at(100)
# => 1..100

# New start
p range.start_at(5)
# => 1..5
```